# Keeping whitespace outside of root element with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I'm using XSLT to process an XML document that is under source control and must remain human readable.

As such, I'm trying to edit a text node, but keep the rest of the document exactly as is.

I'm finding that whitespace outside of the root element is being stripped. Specifically a newline between the XML declaration and the root element's open tag, and a newline at the end of the document.

When I add the `indent=yes` attribute to the `xsl:output` element, a newline does appear at the end of the document. However, the newline between the XML declaration and the root element's open tag is still missing.

What is my stylesheet missing?

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:param name="newVersion"/>
    <xsl:template match="/project/version/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$newVersion" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.nuance</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-test-repo</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>test-repo-1</artifactId>
    <name>test-repo-1</name>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</project>
```

Expected Result — only text in `/project/version`has changed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.nuance</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-test-repo</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>test-repo-1</artifactId>
    <name>test-repo-1</name>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</project>
```

Actual Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.nuance</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-test-repo</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>test-repo-1</artifactId>
    <name>test-repo-1</name>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you using Java to launch XSLT transformation?

Comment: There is no way your XSLT produces the result you claim: your XML declares a default namespace which your stylesheet ignores.

Comment: Yes, I am using Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java, please try to add the following line:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty("http://www.oracle.com/xml/is-standalone", "yes");
```

Comment: I had tried ```standalone="yes"``` on the ```xsl:output``` element, but that added a ```standalone="yes" to the XML declaration. For some reason, this solution does not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While the XML spec allows white space text as Misc before and after the root element, most abstract models like infoset and tree models like Xdm do not include such white space text as nodes in the model.

Therefore, as far as the XSLT processor is concerned, the markup `<?xml version="1.0"?><root/>` and `<?xml version="1.0"?> <root/>` result in the same tree with a document node containing a single element node as the children. Only comments and processing instructions outside of the root element would show up in the Xdm tree.

So your stylesheet doesn't do anything wrong, your expectation about preservation of such white space text nodes is simply not met by the spec and the implementation you use.

As for the output, the serialization, I guess chances are that other XSLT processors do output a line break between the XML declaration and the root element on serialization of a result tree.

Comment: Outputting a line break before the first start tag is indeed common practice, but it is technically incorrect, because if the result is used as an external parsed entity rather than a document entity, the whitespace will be significant.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I didn't remember that. Are there any serialization settings in XSLT 3 to tell the processor whether it should serialize as a document entity or as an external parsed entity?

Comment: No. Saxon plugs the gap with `saxon:require-well-formed`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this can produce an acceptable result:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="project"/>

<xsl:param name="newVersion"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/project/version/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="$newVersion" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFA1D

Comment: This did not make much of a difference. But thanks for the programming style tips. :-)

Comment: How does the result in the demo differ from the result you want?

Comment: - It added spaces to what were empty blank lines.
- It added extra blank lines between the last three elements within the project element.
- When I happened to change my indent from 4 to 2 spaces, it appeared insist on 4 spaces on output.

Given the source control aspect of this issue this is the worst kind of change.

As I mentioned (belatedly) elsewhere, I am working in Java. The site you reference uses .Net. I chalk the difference in results to a difference in processor.

Comment: I do not see any of that. The demo uses the Saxon processor, which is first and foremost a Java processor.

Comment: Different JDKs? Different default transformers? Different default DOM parsers? I have compared the results "by hand" (that is, eyeballed them) in a debugger run of a JUnit test and these were the issues I saw. Obviously environments are different. Exactly how, I don't know. You've demonstrated through the fiddle site that your solution can work. It just didn't work for me.

Comment: Your stylesheet declares `version="2.0"` so I assumed you were using a processor that supports XSLT 2.0. It seem you're not and find it much more difficult to control the serializing. If you are working in Java, you'd be well advised to switch to Saxon. For many more reasons than this.